# Dynamic plugin loading in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins

**Background info**

In CakePHP v2.xx (I am using v2.2.3), plugins must be loaded in `app/Config/bootstrap.php` which is fine if you know which plugins are going to be loaded.

I am building a CMS, which is going to support pluginable `"modules"`. This of course lead me to building the modules as plugins to go in `app/Plugin` and I added a subdirectory called `Modules` to group them in (`app/Plugin/Modules/`), again fine. However, in order to have these load dynamically (modules will be controllable in terms of enable/disable install/uninstall etc) I would have to scan the directory from the bootstrap, as database access is unavailable at that point. Though this would still load disabled plugins if the folder exists in the folder.

**Main question**

Is there a way of effectively loading all plugins found in a certain folder (preferably using DB info) - I don't want to run `CakePlugin::loadAll()` unless I can specify which folder within `app/Plugin` it should load them from (which doesn't seem to be possible from what I've read in the documentation).

**Simplified**

- How can I load all plugins from `app/Plugin/Modules` (custom plugin subfolder)
- Can I query a model from within the `app/Config/bootstrap.php` somehow to aid loading a custom list of plugins

---

**Update:- Resolution**

Thanks to burzum for his answer - it wasn't EXACTLY what I needed, but extremely close and I managed to sort out my answer using his code. For any future visitors my final code is below:

```
App::uses('ClassRegistry','Utility');
$Module = ClassRegistry::init('Module');
$activeModules = $Module->loadActive();
foreach($activeModules as $mod)
{
    CakePlugin::load($mod);
}
```

NB: I didn't use burzum's suggestion of `loadAll` as it still loads all plugins, however I don't want to load the plugins at all if the database says they're disabled/not installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I load all plugins from app/Plugin/Modules (custom plugin
>   subfolder)

[Read the doc block of App::build()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-class-App.html#256-353) and call it in bootstrap.php before you load any plugin. Add your custom path to the plugin paths.

> Can I query a model from within the app/Config/bootstrap.php somehow
>   to aid loading a custom list of plugins

```
App::uses('ClassRegistry', 'Utility');
$Module = ClassRegistry::init('Module');
$modules = $Module->loadActive();
foreach ($modules as $module) {
    CakePlugin::load($module);
}
```

Make sure that loadActive() or whatever you name your method returns an array structure that matches what CakePlugin::load() expects.

Updated the question to fix the part about loadAll() vs load().

Comment: Thanks for the help - I'd already added the path with `App::build()`, but `loadAll` still loads everything it finds. I ended up using most of your second block of code, but looped through the array to call `CakePlugin::load()` individually (as shown in my updated question)

Comment: Yes, I've misread the description of the options array, updated the answer so that other people get it right the first time.